# Forcing Google Adsense to load after actual webpage?

Tags: php, adsense

On my site,  I have google adsense in my right hand side nav bar. The problem I find is because the adsence code is placed before the actual webpage content, as I use includes in php to pull my site template in, I find that it loads the adsence code first and can cause everything else to load after it.

Does anyone know of a good way that I can force it to loads after the actual webpage loads?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Google Adsense load last after the rest of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487511/how-to-make-google-adsense-load-last-after-the-rest-of-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i managed to solve it. I found this: [How to make Google Adsense load last after the rest of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487511/how-to-make-google-adsense-load-last-after-the-rest-of-page) and someone replied with a link to show how to do it. Solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/sleep.php

Something like this?

Or use a javascript settimeout and display an ajax loader gif whilst it loads.

More info on AJAX preloaders: http://blog.twostepmedia.co.uk/jquery-ajax-gif-preloader/

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit your site's template, then you should be able to edit the Adsense loader. Find where it is being included on your template and move it down, to just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: in addition, the OP could use some simple css to place it wherever he chooses

Comment: i am not sure what you mean exactly, if i move the adsense code just before the end `</body>` tag it's position is no longer in the nav bar? maybe i am not understanding you properly.