# Open Adsense Ads On Page Load

Tags: html, wordpress, adsense

i have a website that has adsense ads embedded in the right sidebar area. the site basically contains multiple posts. I want the ads to launch whenever a post is viewed, i.e., when a user clicks on a link to view the post, it should launch the ad as well..

adsense provides a javascript that, i think, wouldn't suffice. please suggest a workaround..

Comment: Does "launch" mean that you want the ads to be clicked programmatically?

Comment: yep, i guess..i ve seen on sites when the ads fire when u click on a link..i want a similar thing..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Google Adsense load last after the rest of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487511/how-to-make-google-adsense-load-last-after-the-rest-of-page)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot automatically click Google Adsense ads. This is called click fraud and Google will detect it and ban you (and keep any money you've earned).

Comment: so m guessing no ad-service would offer such service>

Comment: Yes, for the same reasons I can't throw groceries in someone else's shopping cart and then force them to pay for them.